# How do I convert from std::wstring _TCHAR []?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, tchar

I'm using a library and sends me `std::wstring` from one of its functions, and another library that requires `_TCHAR []` to be sent to it. How can I convert it?

Comment: Will the other library accept a **const** _TCHAR[]? I.e., does it intend to change the data? If it does, could it possibly **lengthen** the data?

Comment: Yes, a const _TCHAR[] is okay. It doesn't intend to change the data.

Comment: What's _TCHAR? _TCHAR is defined as wchar_t in a Unicode build, but as char in a non Unicode build.

Comment: I guess wchar_t because I'm using wstrings?

Comment: Just because you're using std::wstring doesn't mean _TCHAR is wchar_t. Look up your build defines.

Comment: Where is that? If I move the mouse over _TCHAR in visual studio, it says typedef wchar_t _TCHAR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using Unicode build, std::wstring.c_str() is what you need. Note that c_str() guarantees that the string it returns is null-terminated.

e.g.

```
void func(const wchar_t str[])
{
}

std::wstring src;
func(src.c_str());
```

If you're using non-Unicode build, you'll need to convert the Unicode string to non Unicode string via [WideCharToMultiByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa908730.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

As *@Zach Saw* said, if you build only for Unicode you can get away with `std::wstring.c_str()`, but conteptually it would be better to define a `tstring` (a `typedef` for `std::basic_string<TCHAR>`) so you can safely use this kind of string flawlessly with all the Windows and library functions which expect `TCHAR`s<sup>1</sup>.

For additional fun you should define also all the other string-related C++ facilities for `TCHAR`s, and create conversion functions `std::string`/`std::wstring` <=> `tstring`.

Fortunately, this work has already been done; see [here](http://smartwin.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/smartwin/SmartWin/SmartUtil/tstring.h?revision=1.12&view=markup) and [here](http://smartwin.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/smartwin/SmartWin/SmartUtil/StringConversion.h?view=markup).

---

1. Actually no compiled library function can really expect a `TCHAR *`, since `TCHAR`s are resolved as `char`s or `wchar_t`s at compile time, but you got the idea.

Comment: A C++ library could expect a `TCHAR*`. After all, C++ has overloading on argument type. It would be an unusual build, but MSVC's name mangling can handle it. Most Win32 DLLs also expect a TCHAR, although the name mangling is set up up via the "A/W" suffix macros.

Comment: A compiled C++ library cannot really expect `TCHAR *`, it will have two separate (overloaded) functions, one accepting `char *` and one accepting `wchar_t *`, otherwise it couldn't work with projects compiled with different settings of the `_UNICODE` macro. That was what I intended with my note.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ATL and MFC String Conversion Macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3.aspx). This works regardless of whether you are compiling in `_UNICODE` or ANSI mode.

You can use these macros even if you aren’t using MFC. Just include the two ATL headers shown in this example:

```
#include <string>

#include <Windows.h>

#include <AtlBase.h>
#include <AtlConv.h>

int main()
{
    std::wstring myString = L"Hello, World!";

    // Here is an ATL string conversion macro:
    CW2T pszT(myString.c_str());

    // pszT is now an object which can be used anywhere a `const TCHAR*`
    // is required. For example:
    ::MessageBox(NULL, pszT, _T("Test MessageBox"), MB_OK);

    return 0;
}
```